# How to specify source files that shouldn't be compiled in Bazel?

Tags: c++, bazel, poco-libraries

I'm trying to wrap around Poco library. And it contains code like this:

```
#if defined(POCO_OS_FAMILY_UNIX)
#include "Path_UNIX.cpp"
#elif defined(POCO_OS_FAMILY_WINDOWS) && defined(POCO_WIN32_UTF8)
#if defined(_WIN32_WCE)
#include "Path_WINCE.cpp"
#else
#include "Path_WIN32U.cpp"
#endif
#elif defined(POCO_OS_FAMILY_WINDOWS)
#include "Path_WIN32.cpp"
#endif
```

But Bazel complains about `Path_*.cpp` files because I don't mention them in `srcs` section. What is a proper section to mention these files: they are private, sources, and shouldn't be compiled on their own?

<s>My current workaround is to put them into `data` section, but it doesn't match conceptually.</s>

#### Update:

actually `data` section doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `hdrs` attribute. Also if these files are required by dependent libraries you can add it to `textual_hdrs`.

https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library.textual_hdrs

If you need to hide these files from dependent rules you'll need to use a genrule (or patch command at the repository level) to copy the files to a .h extension and modify the source file that includes the files.